# Using factory inside route controller

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs

I have factory like this:

```
angular.module('commentsApp')
        .factory("getCommentsFactory", getCommentsFactory);

function getCommentsFactory(scope, $http)
{
    return {
        getComments: getComments
    };

    function getComments()
    {
        return $http.get("/api/comments/" + scope.param)
                .then(getCommentsComplete)
                .catch(getCommentsFailed);

        function getCommentsComplete(data) {
        //GET ALL USER AND COMMENTS TOGETHER
            return data;
        }

        function getCommentsFailed(error) {
            scope.setLoading(false);
            return error;
        }
    }

}
```

When I try to call this factory from my contrller like this:

```
.controller('CommentsCtrl',function($scope,$http,$routeParams,getCommentsFactory){
              $scope.param = $routeParams.id;
              $scope.comments = [];
              getCommentsFactory.getComments()
                      .then(function(data){
                          console.log(data);
              });
...
```

I get error:

> Error: [$injector:unpr]
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.3/$injector/unpr?p0=scopeProvider%20%3C-cope%20%3C-%20getCommentsFactory
>       at Error (native)
>       at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular.min.js:6:416
>       at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular.min.js:40:375
>       at Object.d [as get] (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular.min.js:38:364)
>       at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular.min.js:40:449
>       at d (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular.min.js:38:364)
>       at Object.e [as invoke] (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular.min.js:39:124)
>       at Object.$get (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular.min.js:37:98)
>       at Object.e [as invoke] (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular.min.js:39:156)
>       at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular.min.js:40:478

Anyone know what is problem?

Comment: So here we need to remove scope from factory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is you are injecting something called "scope" in your factory, but there is no scope you can inject there.

If you need a value from your controller there you should pass it as a parameter in the function. You cannot inject a controller scope in a factory.

Comment: I fix it but still same probelm.

Comment: Can you update your question with your fix and the current problem?